# Nginx not serving site unless index.html not mentioned in URL

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

This is probably something very trivial. But I can't seem to get Nginx to serve `index.html` if I just enter the IP-address in the browser's address bar (for example: 194.XXX.YYY.ZZZ)

To serve `index.html`, I have to explicitly type `194.XXX.YYY.ZZZ/index.html`. If I don't, I just see Nginx's default welcome page

Below is my nginx .conf file. Have I made an obvious mistake? Or, have I missed something?

Thanks for your help,
Abhinav

```
    1 
    2 server {
    3     listen         80;
    4     listen         [::]:80 ;
    5     server_name    194.XXX.YYY.ZZZ;
    6 
    7     location / {
    8       root /home/admin/fe/sandbox/current/web/;
    9       index index.html;
    10     }
    11 
    12     gzip             on;
    13     gzip_comp_level  3;
    14     gzip_types       text/plain text/css application/javascript image/*;
    15 }
```

Comment: Did you try moving the `root` directive outside the location block?

Comment: Also try removing the trailing slash from `root`.

Comment: Did both. Didn't work.

Comment: Does it matter how I restart Nginx after changing the .conf file? Should I use `sudo systemctl restart nginx` or `nginx -s reload`?

Comment: Got it!! Seems I needed to clear my browser's cache first to force a reload. Original Nginx conf was just fine. Thanks though everyone

Answer (score 2):

```
location / {

                root /var/www/html/folder name;
                try_files $uri $uri.html /index.html;
                index  index.html index.htm;

}
```

Try to  serve file by this way.